# Log in loop problems

Tags: 14.04

I am a newbie to Linux and Ubuntu I installed the 14.04 lts for 32 bit, after installation I get the same issues as others, I have checked previously and tried the fixes recommended but nothing its possibly the way i am entering at the terminal not using correct way of asking for the checks etc, I appreciate any help especially if it can give me detail or point me in the right direction to fix as I want to learn

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. Please try formulating a concrete question. First read this: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: -1 for no concrete question and no explaining an issue

Answer (score 0):

May be it with the issue with the   `.Xauthority` file in your home folder

on login screen hit `ctrl + Alt + f2`
login

then

`cd /home/username/`

`sudo chown username : username .Xauthority`

replace username with your username

then hit `ctrl + Alt + F7`
and try login